# How to display a rectangle node with label through PREFUSE visualization toolkit in Java?

Tags: prefuse

I can render a node with the help of either:

1. LabelRenderer (that shows the text content of the node)

or

2. ShapeRenderer (that shows the shape of the node)

I want a mix-up of both, means the shape should be displayed with tthe text (label) on it.

How can I do this. I tried to add both renderers (label and shape renderers) to the visualization but it didn't work.

A lot of thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Decorators for this purpose.